# Change order of dropdowns on single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the order of the dropdowns on a variable product in WooCommerce. I want the `quantity` dropdown to be the first dropdown, and then the `variation` dropdowns afterwards.

Here is what it looks like now:
[image: Here is what it looks like now]

I know my way around PHP, MySQL, and some other languages, but I haven't written any custom code yet.

Any suggestions would be outstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using WooCommerce attributes.

1. Go through Products > Attributes , in your dashboard.
2. Select your attribute (eg. Variation Option1) ,
3. There's an option called "Default sort order", change it to "Custom Ordering".
4. Go to your product edit page,
5. In product data section, Attributes tab, change the order of attributes using drag and drop
6. Save your product
7. Done!